# Intellij compiler error - failed to copy from temporary location to output directory

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ was working fine on my machine and suddenly it started to give me these errors when I compile

"failed to copy from temporary location to output directory: path-of-the-temporary-compiled class-in-the-user-temp-directory"

If I remove the module from the project and add it again and compile the file, it works fine for sometime and then starts giving this error.

Tried cleaning up the user dir, shutdown and restart, etc. No luck

IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3 on Windows 7. Also on IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Did you try "invalidate caches" in the file menu?

Comment: Tried that. It did not work.

Comment: Did you take a look at idea.log? According to com.intellij.compiler.impl.javaCompiler.BackendCompilerWrapper the process details and error must be logged to file. Seems like an IOException.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the file, it does contain `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\kuldeep\AppData\Local\Temp\compile4290854641303283029output\***` but why is it storing and then looking up for the class files in Temp folder?

Comment: How much free sapce do you have on your drive? And how much does your project take after comilation? If you have maven module please give the full size of target folder in module directory after clean install.

Comment: I have lot of free space (more than 12 GB). Could you please give details about where to give the full size? didn't get that.

Comment: I assumed you have maven project. When you build your project maven creates "target" folder in the directory with your module (the same directory where you call `mvn clean install`to build the project from command line). Roughly saud, IDEA can require the same amount of space to do its own compilation inside your home/project directory.... so if your target folder takes 1 GB, than you should have 2GB free space to be sure that this is not a problem... but if you say you have 12GB of free space, than this probably is not thing here... the best to do is to check free space when problem occures.

Comment: Even when problem occurs I have 12 GB free space.

Answer (score 5):

I got the exact error.
I fixed this problem by Rebuilding the project.

Click on **Build -> Rebuild Project.**.

This will resolve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: it helped - using jsp+ANT, was getting errors about compiler is unable to copy to .idea/sonarlint/...

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error but did not see any answer to this question so thought of posting my solution(workaround) for this:

As the error mentioned failure to copy from temporary location which was point to Temp folder so I tried cleaning up the Temporary files etc. using Disk Cleanup of `C:\`  and that resolved the error for me.

**NOTE:** This is just a temporary workaround, I would love to get a real solution to this. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and restarted the IntelliJ IDEA which fixed the problem. I think when I restarted, the process was killed and associated files in temp files were delete..

Next time when I get it I will compare the no of files in temp folder before and after restart.

Answer (score 0):

It's works by set resources config in the pom file